# How to remove relic from desktop app display

Tags: software-uninstall

Enclosed please find a photo of my Ubuntu desktop application display. There is the vestige, relic in last row,, left after uninstallation of “MyChrome” app from Ubuntu repository. Have you idea how to remove that relic?

[image]

Comment: Seach your home folder for `.desktop` files: `find ~ -name "*.desktop"`. Remove any suspicious files.

Comment: There where no suspicious files, but relic egzist. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the `.desktop` files that Chromium created to provide you with launchers to these Chrome apps in a folder `.local/share/applications` in your home directory. `.local` is a hidden folder (dot in front of the name). You can reveal it in your file manager by turning the option `Show hidden files` on, or just by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. this keyboard combination toggles the option on and off.

In the `.local` folder, find `share` the `applications`, where all the lauchers that exist only for your user live. These include the Chrome apps.

For your information, system wide .desktop files are located in /usr/share/applications, except for packages installed with the snap packaging system.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that "MyChrome" packages were installed with the snap packaging system.

Comment: Finally I have fond that relics in varlib/snapd/desktop/applications/mychrome_chrome.desktop
varlib/snapd/sequence/mychrome.json, but I have no permission to delete them. How to get permission?